# serviceWorker can't find global variable

Tags: typescript, service-worker, angular-service-worker

i have a service worker and it can't find a global variable. i'm not sure why, can someone explain why it doen't see global variable and how to fix it?

```
declare var myGlobalVar: Function;

const myFunction = async() {
  //doing stuff
  //calling myGlobalVar which give me following error
}
```

error i get while running serviceWorker:

```
:Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: myGlobalVar is not defined
```

Comment: Side note - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/319344/are-global-variables-okay-to-use-in-asynchronous-programs

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a TypeScript issue (... well, not directly), this is a JavaScript issue.

`declare` tells the TS compiler to bugger off and trust you that that variable will be available at runtime. It's a contract between you and your code. It does **not** provide anything to the runtime. `declare`d variables are called "ambient" for this reason - they go away during compilation.

See this for more information on [Ambient Declarations](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/intro.html).

You're missing, on the JavaScript side, the declaration of `myFunction`. For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myGlobalVar() {
    // whatever
  }
</script>

<script src="../bundle.js"></script>
```

where `bundle.js` is the output of `tsc`.